# mySQL query that consists of output obtained from another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question that I can't find an answer to...

I have a table with a lot of columns that are relevant at different times and situations, so usually, only 5-10 columns are relevant (out of 45 columns in total).

Therefore, I created a query that produces a single row in which all the names of the relevant columns appear separated by commas. This is the output for example:

| Column_1 |
| --- |
| name, date, age, from |

The query I would like to create (Without success) should select from the table only the columns that I got from the first query, i.e .:

```
SELECT ("the output obtained from the first query") FROM table1
```

So in the end, what will actually run is this:

```
SELECT name, date, age, from FROM table1
```

I would be happy for your help,

Thank you very much

Comment: You would need dynamic SQL if you want a variable number or types of columns in your query.

Comment: Using reserved words such as `name, date, from` as field names will likely cause issues. What programming interface are you using?